# A specific problem with alignment of arrays with brackets

Tags: numbering, vertical-alignment, arrays, brackets

In the example below I would like to have the "on" exactely below each other, i.e. to put it in one table - that is of course without any problem, BUT the bracket and the numbering! How to get it in one table with the same bracket (only for the first three lines) and the same numbering (one number for the first three lines, then one number for each left line). How to do it? If this is alredy answered, please give me a link, I was not able to find it. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\vnull}{\boldsymbol{0}}
\newcommand{\vsigma}{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}
\newcommand{\vchi}{\boldsymbol{\chi}}
\newcommand{\vu}{\boldsymbol{u}}
\newcommand{\vf}{\boldsymbol{f}}
\newcommand{\vp}{\boldsymbol{p}}
\newcommand{\vn}{\boldsymbol{n}}
\newcommand{\vnu}{\boldsymbol{\nu}}



\begin{equation} \label{equ:eqDbcNbc3D1}
\left.
\begin{array}{rll}
\mbox{div} \, \vsigma(\vu^k) + \vf^k = \vnull & \mbox{ in } & \Omega^k\\[2mm]
\vu^k=\vnull & \mbox{ on } & \Gamma_u^k\\[2mm]
\vsigma^k \vn^k  - \vp^k = \vnull & \mbox{ on } & \Gamma_p^k\\[2mm]
\end{array}
\right\} \ \ \ k=1,2,
\end{equation}
\begin{eqnarray}
u_\nu -d\leq 0, \ \sigma_\nu \leq 0, \ \sigma_\nu (u_\nu - d) = 0 & \mbox{ on } & \Gamma_c^1\\[2mm]\label{equ:eqDbcNbc3D2}
\vsigma^1\vnu = (\vsigma^2\circ\vchi)\vnu & \mbox{ on } & \Gamma_c^1\label{equ:eqDbcNbc3D3}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're lucky that the equations to be merged are three:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\vnull}{\bm{0}}
\newcommand{\vsigma}{\bm{\sigma}}
\newcommand{\vchi}{\bm{\chi}}
\newcommand{\vu}{\bm{u}}
\newcommand{\vf}{\bm{f}}
\newcommand{\vp}{\bm{p}}
\newcommand{\vn}{\bm{n}}
\newcommand{\vnu}{\bm{\nu}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\DIV}{div}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\DIV \vsigma(\vu^k) + \vf^k = \vnull &\qquad&& \text{in $\Omega^k$} \notag \\
\vu^k=\vnull &&& \text{on $\Gamma_u^k$}
  \smash{\left.\begin{aligned}\\ \\ \\ \end{aligned}\right\}}
  \quad k=1,2
  \label{equ:eqDbcNbc3D1} \\
\vsigma^k \vn^k  - \vp^k = \vnull &&& \text{on $\Gamma_p^k$} \notag \\
u_\nu -d\leq 0, \ \sigma_\nu \leq 0, \ \sigma_\nu (u_\nu - d) = 0 &&& \text{on $\Gamma_c^1$}
  \label{equ:eqDbcNbc3D2} \\
\vsigma^1\vnu = (\vsigma^2\circ\vchi)\vnu &&& \text{on $\Gamma_c^1$}
  \label{equ:eqDbcNbc3D3}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Never use `eqnarray`. Also `\boldsymbol` should better be `\bm`.

Comment: excellent, thank you, but I would need the same space as before "on" also after "on", before \Gamma etc. I have tried it somehow analogically, but it does not work, ...how to do this?

Comment: @user70214 Just add `\quad` or something like that; but I don't think you gan in clarity.